# Sorting an ArrayList, into object type and then alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have defined an arrayList

Each of these objects have there own name etc. 
I would like to sort them by type, so all watermelons are together and pears are together etc. then for them to be sorted alphabetically within each time.

Something using

```
public int compare(String[] first, String[] second) {
    return first[1].compareTo(second[1]);
}
```

Also is it possible to just do this in an already created class, to avoid doing it in a new class.

Comment: Why are you passing in a `String` array into your comparator?

Comment: Read the [collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/index.html#sorting).

Comment: Can [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property) help?

Comment: Use a comparator, but not for `String` for `Food` type, you can make a protected method in food class that put the priorirty for each class, also you can make your class Food implements `Comparable<Food>`

Answer (score 3):

Close, but you won't be able to pass `String` arrays as parameters to the compare method. You need to create a `Comparator<Food>` and the parameters will be `Food` references.

Then in the `compare(Food f1, Food f2)` method you'll need to compare the class, and if they're the same, then the name.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but I want to clarify: you can pass String[] to compare.  `ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();`  `Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String[]>() { public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) { return 0; } });`  This just isn't what the OP should be using.  He should, as you say, be using Comparator<Food>.

Comment: Well obviously. But for a Comparator<Food> the parameters can't be String arrays.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally submitted my comment before it was fully baked.  I just didn't want someone to think that it is impossible to use String[] with Comparator.  Your answer is helpful and on task, I did upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty close. You can do something like this (one-shot with anonymous implementation of `Comparator` interface so you don't need a new class):

```
Collections.sort(foodList, new Comparator<Food>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Food food1, Food food2) {
        int result = 0;
        if(food1.getType().equals(food2.getType())) {
            result = food1.getName().compareTo(food2.getName());
        } else {
            result = food1.getType().compareTo(food2.getType()); 
        }

        return result;
    }
});
```

Another way is to have `Food` implement `Comparable<T>` and use the same logic for the `compareTo(T o)` implementation.

The comparison works by first checking to see if the types of the food are equal (assuming the food type has an applicable `equals()` method). If they are equal, the comparison needs to be done on the basis of their names. Otherwise, the comparison will be done based on the food type.

Comment: You seem to have some sort of syntax error in your code. I can't say without seeing the code in question.

Comment: Your code looks nothing like the example I provided. That's not how you would instantiate `Comparator<T>`. There is no class called `comparator`, which you're trying to instantiate. You can't even instantiate `Comparator<T>` in that manner because it is an interface. Look at my answer to see how I did it.

Comment: Yes, you need to provide an in-line implementation. It's basically an anonymous inner class.

Comment: Your questions are pretty basic. You need to brush up on your Java syntax to figure out how inner classes are instantiated. You really only need to look at how I did it above. If you have a new question, please start it in a new post.

Comment: Have you imported `Comparator`? :)

Comment: Quite strange. There might be other issues in your code perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `Comparable` interface in your `Food` implementations or subclasses.  Though it is easy to write an implementation that works for your case, it is not as trivial as it seems to write a completely correct `Comparable` implementation, especially concerning inheritance.  See *Effective Java*, item 12 for a good documentation of the requirements and of common pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

Your compare method name is wrong. It would be compareTo of Comparable interface.:

```
public int compareTo(Fruit second) {
 return this.getWaterMelon().compareTo(second.getWaterMelon());
}
```

Comment: You're mixing up `Comparable<T>` and `Comparator<T>`. `Comparable<T>` has `compareTo(T o)` whereas `Comparator<T>` has `compare(T o1, T o2)`.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that your `compare()` method will need to return weighed value for your `type` compareTo() difference + `name` compareTo() difference.
Something like

```
public int compare(Food food1, Food food2) {
   int result = 0;
   result = food1.getType().compareTo(food2.getType()) * someMultiplier + food1.getName().compareTo(food2.getName());
   return result;
}
```

EDIT:
This is the usage that I was suggesting...

```
public class ComparatorTest {

    static class ComaparableObject implements Comparable {
        private Object value1;
        private Object value2;

        public ComaparableObject(Object value1, Object value2) {
            this.value1 = value1;
            this.value2 = value2;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            int multiplier = 65535;
            ComaparableObject co = (ComaparableObject) o;
            int result = (value1.hashCode() * multiplier + value2.hashCode()) - (co.value1.hashCode() * multiplier + co.value2.hashCode()) ;
            return result;
        }

        public Object getValue1() {
            return value1;
        }

        public void setValue1(Object value1) {
            this.value1 = value1;
        }

        public Object getValue2() {
            return value2;
        }

        public void setValue2(Object value2) {
            this.value2 = value2;
        }

        public String toString() {
            String result = "value1=" + value1 + ", " + "value2=" + value2;
            return result;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ComaparableObject> al;


        al = new ArrayList<ComaparableObject>();
        ComaparableObject co;
        int value1 = 2;
        co = new ComaparableObject(value1, 3);
        al.add(co);
        co = new ComaparableObject(value1, 1);
        al.add(co);
        co = new ComaparableObject(value1, 2);
        al.add(co);
        value1 = 1;
        co = new ComaparableObject(value1, 3);
        al.add(co);
        co = new ComaparableObject(value1, 1);
        al.add(co);
        co = new ComaparableObject(value1, 2);
        al.add(co);

        System.out.println("Before sort: " + al);

        Collections.sort(al, new Comparator<ComaparableObject>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ComaparableObject co1, ComaparableObject co2) {
                int result;
                result = co1.compareTo(co2);
                return result;
            }
        });

        System.out.println("After sort: " + al);

        }

}
```

Comment: Err, no. That wouldn't sort by type and then by name. Read the compareTo javadoc.

Comment: @JBNizet I am familiar with compareTo() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29   

I think that you will find that it does work. I am adding full testable code in my answer above.

Comment: I fail to see how your test illustrates sorting food by type then by name. What would you multiply to your multiplier when comparing ("fruit", "banana") with ("meat", "beef")? Why implement it in such a convoluted way when you just need to return the comparison result of the two types, or the comparison result of the two names if the type comparison is 0? (And I don't even mention that your algorithm would fail with larger numbers due to integer overflow).

Comment: @JBNizet value1 is (equivalent of) type, value2 is (equivalent of) name

Comment: OK. How do you multiply "fruit" by 65535?

Comment: @JBNizet What does String.compareTo() method returns? Multiply that by the multiplier to get the weighed value that is grater than the value of next (less significant) part.

Comment: It returns an undefined positive value, an undefined negative value, or 0. And you have to call compareTo with an argument to get such a result. What would you pass as argument? How, from "fruit" and `int compareTo(String other)`, would you get an integer value to multiply with 65535? Supposing you get such a value, how would you deal with integer overflow?

Comment: @JBNizet 65535 was an example, a figure to give you a good "step up". That i the reason why I had the `Object` `value1` and `value2`, This way you can override hashCode() to return good numerical representation of `Object` state/value. BTW: String.compareTo() "Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings." `return c1 - c2;` or `return len1 - len2;`